# substr() not working to trim the_content() in wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<div class="wpex-recent-posts-content clr">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><p>
<?php
    $content = the_content();
    echo substr($content,0,100);
?>
</p>
</div>
```

here `echo substr($content,0,100);` is not working to crop content from 0 to 100. This is located in `my_theme/functions/widgets/widget-portfolio-posts-thumbs.php`

Comment: Did you check $content? Is it printing the content?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = strip_tags($content);
echo substr($content, 0, 100);
```

Comment: Not bad, but it will be better.

if(strlen($content) >25){
                                    echo substr($content, 0, 50).'...';
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                       echo $content; 
                                    }

Comment: But what if you like this for the index.php page and still want to keep the readmore as in used `<?php the_content( 'Read more ...' ); ?>`? So to load a teaser starting at char 205 and then the built in number of chars followed by a readmore..

Answer (score 4):

That's because [the_content()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) actually outputs the content. What you want to use is [get_the_content()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content).